# Same location with different time in the year PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, utc, timestamp-with-timezone

I got an issue with timestamptz (timestamp with timezone). I have New York time, ex: **2pm NY EST**. I will input it as **14:00:00 - 04:00** (UTC-4) because it is July now. However, when it starts from November, it will be **14:00:00 - 05:00** (UTC-5). And it will be turn back to UTC -4 in the following year. How can I do to convert it automatically?

I would like that it will convert to the UTC -5 and UTC-4 automatically depends on the system time.

Comment: You keep saying "it will turn..." but nothing you stored will change. Use "timestamp with time zone" and it will store an absolute (UTC time) then say what timezone you want to view it in.

Answer (score 1):

If I got the question right You can use `at time zone 'America/New_York'` in your SQL queries. Something like that:

```
postgres=# select '2023-07-15 13:00:00-04:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'America/New_York';
      timezone
---------------------
 2023-07-15 13:00:00
(1 row)

postgres=# select '2023-01-15 13:00:00-04:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'America/New_York';
      timezone
---------------------
 2023-01-15 12:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think it will be fine if there is only time that in NY. But, How can we do with different timezone in the same column ? For example, there is other value like "15:00:00 + 05:00" in France at now and will convert to +6:00 from Nov

Comment: I think I have found out the solution. I will added one more column and input the time zone into it, then, I could query as the way you did. Thank you so much!